# How to connect keyboard to external synth module through a DAW

Tags: midi, daw

I have a Yamaha DGX520, I am able to connect to LMMS (my current DAW) and obtain sounds through the computer through the MIDI-in option; however, I cannot seem to connect to my Kurzweil PC2R sound module (even though it is connected as my MIDI-out).

Essentially I want to play the sounds of my PC2R module and just use the DAW as a connection.

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down the issue? Are you able to make sound out of the PC2R through your DAW using just your computer keyboard? Then after that, connect your DGX keyboard and see if you can trigger MIDI notes in the DAW with that? If both of those scenarios are true, I have a hard time believing it wouldn't work the way you think.